# date diff function in query of google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, date-difference

I got the below result using the formula

```
={query(SALES!A2:Y ,"Select B, C, D, G,  P,  Sum(T), datediff(now(), todate(P)) WHERE O ='"&(A1)&"' GROUP BY B, C, D, G, P ORDER BY datediff(now(), todate(P)) DESC Label Sum(T) 'PENDING AMOUNT', datediff(now(), todate(P)) 'OVER DAYS' " ,1)}
```

Now I need the last column status using if (overdue / underdue based on overdays) using the above formula. pl help

```
INV.DATE    INVOICE NUMBER  CUSTOMER NAME   DUE DATE    PENDING AMOUNT  OVER DAYS   STATUS
15-Apr-2020 IBLR001-2021    abc ltd        15-May-2020  ₹2,46,750       93          OVER DUE
21-Apr-2020 IBLR002-2021    xyx            20-Aug-2020  ₹5,87,788       -4          UNDER DUE
```

Comment: Please share a test sheet

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following formula for your `STATUS` column

```
=ArrayFormula(IF((F2:F=0),"",IF(F2:F>0,"OVER DUE","UNDER DUE")))
```

where `F` is your `OVER DAYS` column. You can adjust the ranges according to your needs.

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)